# Number of squares mod n proof confusion

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $n = p_1^{e_1} ...p_r^{e_r}$ , how many squares modulo $n$ are there? How many quadratic residues modulo $n$ are there (i.e. the squares which are coprime to $n$)?

> For both these questions, we can use the Chinese Remainder theorem.
> Let’s solve the second question first. If $p$ is an odd prime, then
> there are $(p − 1)/2$ quadratic residues $\bmod p$. For each such
> quadratic residue $a$, Hensel’s lemma can be applied to $f(x) = x^2 − a$
> to see that $a$ (and anything congruent to $a\bmod p^e$) must be a
> square. **Since there are $p^{e−1}$ such lifts** for every choice of
> $a \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, we see that the number of quadratic residues
> $\bmod p^e$ is $p^{e−1}(p−1)/2 = p^e(1−1/p)·1/2$.

I am confused why Hensel's lemma gives $p^{e-1}$ lifts? I thought Hensel's lemma states there is a unique lift $f(a) \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$ to $f(a + tp) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$, so shouldn't the answer be $(p-1)/2$ squares $\bmod p^e$?

Comment: I agree this is not a great use of terminology. The argument sounds like it's finding $2p^{e-1}$ roots of a fixed polynomial $x^2-a$ modulo $p^e$; but actually it's finding $2$ roots of each of a family of polynomials $x^2-a$, $x^2-(a+p)$, ..., $x^2-(a+p^e-p)$.

Comment: Is the second paragraph a quote from somewhere else? If so it would be good to indicate as such with a blockquote, and link to the source.